# Getting Illegal Instruction error for SHA1MSG1 instruction

Tags: assembly, x86-64

SHA1MSG1 is an Intel instruction for computing an step for calculating SHA1 hash value. I used it as follows (in AT&T syntax):

```
sha1msg1    %xmm14, %xmm13
```

I can compile my code. When I run my code, it gives an error:

```
Illegal instruction (core dumped)
```

I debugged my code using `ida pro` and I got an error for this instruction as follows:

```
401839: got SIGILL signal (Illegal instruction) (exc.code 4, tid 48292)
```

I tried to find an example use of this instruction but I did not find any. I guess I used it correctly according to the [specification](https://software.intel.com/sites/default/files/managed/39/c5/325462-sdm-vol-1-2abcd-3abcd.pdf). Any idea what I did wrong?

BTW, I am using Ubuntu 64bit.

Comment: What's your cpu model? Could it be that it simply doesn't support this instruction? Do you have the `sha` flag in `/proc/cpuinfo`?

Comment: Here is my CPU info: Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU           E5645  @ 2.40GHz

Comment: Looks like your processor doesn't support that instruction. [It was Introduced on Intel Goldmont microarchitecture.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_SHA_extensions)

Comment: Oh, I see. Thanks. How can I mark your comment as answer? Should I?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like your processor doesn't support the SHA1MSG1 instruction.
It was introduced with the [*Goldmont* microarchitecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_SHA_extensions), so its server processors have to be of the [*Denverton* family](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goldmont#Server_processors_(Denverton))(2016) or highter.

Your Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5645 is from the [*Westmere* family](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Westmere_(microarchitecture))(2010), so it doesn't support that instruction.

Wikipedia has [a list of the different microarchitectures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Intel_CPU_microarchitectures#x86_microarchitectures).